# Stylus choose from selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, stylus

I just wonder if I can choose from multiple selectors in Stylus? So I have a code like this :

```
.selector-a,
.selector-b
  display: flex
  //There I need to choose just .selector-a and apply style only to .selector-a
  &[0]//Something like this, maybe?
    background: white
  //There I need to chose just .selector-b and apply style only to .selector-b
  &[1]
    background: black
```

Is there any way to do so in Stylus?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, no.
http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

.selector-a,
.selector-b {
  display: flex
}
.selector-a {
    background: white
}
.selector-b {
    background: black
}

Comment: Yeah, well, I know about this approach, I'm asking about the way to do it in more "Stylus way"